# $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=1$, is $f(x)$ unbounded?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, infinity

> Suppose $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function such that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=1$,then is it true necessarily true that $f(x)$ unbounded?

I think that it will always intersect $y=c$ for every $c\in \mathbb{R}$ and thus cannot be bounded!

Comment: An aside for answers of drhab and user72694 ... Merely saying $f$ is differentiable is not enough to conclude that $f$ is the (Riemann or Lebesgue) integral of $f'$.  But the Mean Value Theorem is still applicable, so we can get the conclusions in those two answers.

Answer (score 6):

If the derivative tends to 1 then in particular it will eventually become bigger than 1/2.  Therefore the function is dominated from below by $\frac{1}{2}x-c$ for a suitable c, and hence tends to infinity.

More precisely, by definition of limit for every $\epsilon>$ there is an $N$ such that if $x>N$ then $f'(x)>1-\epsilon$.   Now choose $\epsilon=1/2$.  Then for every $x>N$ we have $f'(x)>1/2$. Now proceed as above.

Comment: "If the derivative tends to $1$ then in particular it will eventually become bigger than $1/2$"`~ can you explain this point a bit sir?

Answer (score 1):

Choose some $c\in\left(0,1\right)$.

$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f'\left(x\right)=1$
implies the existence of some $x_{0}$ with $x\geq x_{0}\Rightarrow f'\left(x\right)\geq c$.

Then $f\left(x\right)\geq cx+f\left(x_{0}\right)-cx_{0}$ for $x\geq x_{0}$
showing that $f$ is unbounded.